# Is mixing silicone oil with other types of oil safe?

Tags: materials, applied-chemistry

I'm looking to lubricate some nylon gears in a servo motor, and online sources tell me silicone lubricants are one of the best ways to go.

However, when I opened up the servo, I found that it already has lubrication in place, most probably a mineral oil-based one. It looks dry though, and I'm inclined to re-lubricate it anyway.

Would having the two types of lubricant in there be a cause for concern? Should I exert effort to clean it out first?

Conversely, would there be any issues if I apply a mineral oil-based lubricant to gears that are known to have silicone oil?

Comment: So, either (1) clean the motor and regrease, or (2) determine from the data sheet what kind of lubricant they specify.

Comment: Different types of oil might not mix well. They might not be unsafe to mix, but the result might be worse lubrication.

Comment: I've erred on the side of caution and used [multi-purpose synthetic lubricant](https://www.super-lube.com/multi-purpose-lubricant-with-syncolon-ptfe). Their [compatibility chart](https://www.super-lube.com/Content/Images/uploaded/documents/Compatability%20Charts/Super%20Lube%20Multi-Purpose%20Synthetic%20Oil%20with%20Syncolon%20(PTFE).pdf) says that basically all plastics in my house are compatible. I've verified that the existing lube isn't silicone. I still wonder about the question though; please feel free to answer.